# Получение видео с web-камеры

Tags: c#

Как обращаться с web-камерой есть специальная библиотека, с этим проблем нет. Но есть проблема, если камеру воткнуть в карту выдеозахвата, она уже как web-камера не определяется. Подскажите, пожалуйста, какой выход из данной ситуации есть? Ее именно, через карту видеозавхата надо использовать

Comment: Ответ напрашивается сам собой: нужно работать через `специальная библиотека` к карте видеозахвата.

Comment: Наверное данной библиотеки нет в свободном доступе думаю

Comment: Карта видеозахвата никогда не поставляется голой. К ней всегда производитель прикладывает драйвера и программный пакет (видеоредактор?). После установки драйверов в системе появляется устройство видеозахвата, с которым можно работать через DirectX или как-то еще, но это нужно читать доки или много гуглить. А в вашем вопросе даже нет никакой конкретики: хотя бы названий и моделей видеокамеры и карты захвата. Нет названий -> нет конкретики -> болтовня на общие абстрактные темы.

Comment: Карта видеозахвата avermedia c985

Comment: Скачайте [SDK](https://www.avermedia.com/professional/download/sdk#ans_part) в ее поставке есть документация. Остальное в ваших руках и голове.